# Moderator single-handedly deleting my highly-upvoted answer. Is this okay?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

I am referring to this answer: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/83473/1470

The moderator also commented that it is "not salvageable" even though the first part directly answers the question. The answer currently has a score of 16. This looks like deleting answers due to political disagreement.

P.S.
The answer would benefit from me adding these links to articles published on Russian men's rights site "Masculist.ru" that specifically discuss feminism:

- [Short but true history of feminism](https://masculist.ru/blogs/post-2868.html)
- [Feminism=idiotism](https://masculist.ru/blogs/post-2036.html)
- [Feminism or femino-fascism?](https://www.masculist.ru/blogs/post-3756.html)

Comment: By arguing that the deletion was due to political disagreement, you are implying that the answer contained opinions that were disagreeable. As you should be aware, opinions are off-topic on this site. So by making that argument you are actually arguing **for** the deletion on the ground that it was a personal opinion masquerading as an answer.

Comment: @Philipp this can be disagreement with the position, which is described in the answer and attributed to anti-feminists.

Comment: @Philipp the answer admittedly could benefit from more links, so I added them to this post.

Comment: You may want to disclose that it's *your* answer you're discussing here. "The answer would benefit from adding these links" - why not add them, then? Deleted answers can still be edited and flagged for undeletion.

Comment: @F1Krazy oh, indeed, I still can edit it, so I've added the links.

Comment: @Philipp Your argument is a non sequitur: it is entirely possible for "political disagreement" to occur over objective facts; it happens frequently.

Answer (score 9):

The first part of the answer, the first three sentences, addresses the question:

> I can answer from the Russian perspective. In Russan men's rights movement people believe that Feminists are people who want to cement and increase legal and de-facto privilegies of women.
>
> They say that feminism arose when the rights of men and women were already equal except in the areas where men were discriminated, such as conscription or pension.
>
> They believe that the current state of affairs, at least in Russia, is not patriarchy but state-sanctioned misandry or matriarchate, bordering on androcide.

The above is fine as it outlines their position. It would have been better if you had added the sources from the start **and** link parts of your answer to what is said in the source, e.g. using quotes (and maybe a machine translation).

The vast majority of the answer, however, relies on questionable statements which are mostly presented as fact. The community management team raised this with the moderators because it seemed to be mostly editorializing / soapboxing on your part.

Examples of those questionable statements are:

> About 95% of cases of violence happens against men, and police usually avoids investigation if there were no women harmed.

95% isn't a believable figure and it's not backed up by a credible reference. Nevertheless you present this as fact rather than just something these men's rights activists believe.

> It is mostly men who face the bloody consequences in the current armed conflict in Ukraine, while women dance on "naked drunk parties" in Moscow night clubs.

This is an overgeneralization. It's true that a lot of Russian men are dying in the war, but it's not like a similar number of women are out partying. This is you playing to user's emotions which is quite a bit removed from the question of how anti-feminists define feminism.

This suspicion of soapboxing was further confirmed by (now deleted) comments of yours under the answer. For example:

> Also, on the workplace (my experience in banks) guys are required to do work for female coleagues (they often do not even know how to use Excel or write SQL queries) and if you refuse, you get accused of "not working in team". Also, only women are allowed to leave workplace on time, men are expected to sit overtime. Also I saw a lot of women who held the position entirely because of beauty.

> I would sacrifice 2% of salary (or maybe 30%) only to have unlimited free sex as women do. In fact the most of male income goes to the women anyway as a pay for sex. There is a known chart regarding Russia showing how much more women SPEND on themselves than men dispite having less total income. For instance, 3/4 of spendings on footwear are on female footwear. So, the most of their income is not from job but from men directly. To make situation equal, 1/2 of female income should be taken from them and given to men.

Answer (score 3):

If a Moderator deletes your question or answer, the right way to approach is to:

1. Make a post here asking why the Q or A was deleted. *Refrain from attacking anyone based on assumptions.* Simply seek clarifications in your Q.
2. If the deleted Q or A has comments offering feedback, use it to make the changes to your Q or A (note that you can continue to edit a deleted question or answer) or explain in the the Meta post why you have ignored it.
3. Patiently wait for the answers. Some will reply immediately,  some may take a day or two - sometimes deliberately to allow your anger / outrage to calm down. Some may choose not to reply if they feel the comments offer all the necessary clarification. There's nothing you can do about it but be patient.
4. Once you get an answer here, read it carefully and use that feedback to improve your answer (note that you can continue to edit a deleted question or answer). Seek more clarifications through comments, if required.
5. Once you've made all the required changes, and improved the Q or A, click `Undelete` below it. The community will review it and either approve the changes or not accept it. If your answer is not Undeleted, *edit* your Meta question and ask for feedback again. Repeat step 2 to 5.

*(Don't worry - we've all gone ballistic here when our Q or A has been deleted - and later felt embarrassed about such silly things. Hopefully, even if you Q or A is not *Undeleted*, you will have a better understanding of the issue. And if you still can't accept it - well, tough luck. It isn't the end of the world - it's just life being unfair or you not understanding life)*.